# Insert empty element of array into Excel cells

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I have this problem

```psh
$arr = @()
$regex = "blabla"

$arr = $body | Select-String $regex -AllMatches | %{$_.Matches} | %{$_Value}
```

The data extracted should be like this:

```
Empty
Value 1
Value 2
Empty
Value 3
```

When I copy it to Excel rows:

```psh
$row = $worksheet.usedrange.rows.count+1
$usedrange = $worksheet.usedrange
$usedrange.entirecolumn.autofit() | Out-Null

$worksheet.cells.item($row,11) = $arr[$i]
```

the empty value been override by the first available array sequentially and become like this

```
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
Empty
Empty
```

How can I get like the original value that I've extracted before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-String` doesn't produce non-matches, so you don't get a result array with empty fields. You need something like this to preserve empty "results":

```psh
$arr = New-Object Collections.ArrayList
$body | % { $arr += if ($_ -match $pattern) {$_} else {$null} }
```

Note that `$body` must be an array of lines for this to work.